# C++ storing #define as std::string would give size as zero compile time

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, stuck with strange problem. I have a #define 
  in common.h

```
 #define TEXT_VALUE "Alpha"
```

In a method inside program.cpp i want to access the same and want to do something like below

```
 #include common.h

 void TestProgram::TestProgram(){
   std::string test_value = TEXT_VALUE;

   if(test_value.empty()) {//check during compile time if not set then set to default
      test_value = "Beta";
   }
 }
```

But test_value is always set as "Beta" in generated executable... even though common.h has the #define....

If the above is not correct way to do it...any other alternative?

The code works fine on MAC but not on windows i am using Visual Studio 2005 (cannot upgrade:-( )

Comment: Time to compile with debugging info and warnings, i.e. using `g++ -Wall -g` then learn how to use the debugger (i.e. `gdb`)!

Comment: Have you included common.h inside program.cpp ?

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). With the code you provided, augmented to give a meaningful program, I get the expecet result: http://ideone.com/DHEgoa. And the comment is wrong - you are checking at runtime. The length of `std::string` cannot be measured at compiletime.

Comment: Is the first code box of your question a typo? Did you really define TEXT_VALUE as `"Alpha" in common.h file`?

Comment: This is not C, but C++. Removed the C tag

Comment: Given the lack of information, one can only guess, but if `test_value` has static lifetime, and the test is in the constructor of an object with static lifetime, there may be an order of initialization issue.

Comment: The OP was asked for an SSCCE 20 minutes ago and still hasn't bothered to provide one ... vote to close -- er, put on hold.

Comment: Good guess. It's tiresome having people come here with a "strange problem" but without a clue that the problem may lie in parts of the code they *aren't* providing.

Comment: I think his problem is "how to check at compiletime". these informations are easy to find on the net, but it's a beginner, please, don't blame him, and teach him why he's wrong ;)

Comment: @Gana Do you actually have `#include common.h` in your source code? It should say `#include "common.h"`.

Comment: @MagnusHoff If that were accurate, it wouldn't compile. Previously the OP left off a semicolon. The OP can't be bothered to post real code, so this should be closed.

Comment: "The code works fine on MAC " -- Don't fib ... the code you have posted won't work anywhere because it isn't valid and won't compile. Paste the *actual* code here -- the whole thing -- with copy and paste ... do not type it in as you're sure to transcribe it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

To check at compiletime, test with the preprocessor ;)

```
    //common.h
    #define TEXT_VALUE "Alpha"
    //...

    //somwhere
    #ifdef TEXT_VALUE
    std::string test_value = TEXT_VALUE;
    #else
    std::string test_value = "Beta";
    #endif
```

Comment: What is its defined but the string is empty?

Comment: That doesn't sound like what he's asking about (but it's hard to know).  And it doesn't work if `#define TEXT_VALUE ""`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. And just because the OP erroneously refers to compile time doesn't mean that the test should be done at compile time ... people should not be encouraged to use macros or ifdefs in C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "common.h"
std::string test_value = TEXT_VALUE;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if(test_value.empty()) 
    {//check during compile time if not set then set to default
           test_value = "Beta";
    }
    cout<<test_value;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code work for me.

Comment: If the header isn't included then TEXT_VALUE will be undefined and the code won't compile. All we can do is guess because the OP can't be bothered to give accurate information.

Comment: You could at least have indented it properly.

Comment: it works for me on my mac, but not on windows....with visual studio 2005